# MongoDB join two collections using aggregation $lookup or populate in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

Here are two collections' schema

```
var activitySchema = new Schema({

    activity_id: {type: String, index: {unique: true}, required: true}, 

    begin_date : String,
    ...
})

var registrationSchema = new Schema({

    activity_id: {type: String, index: {unique: true}, required: true}, 

    registration_id: {type:String, trim: true, index: true ,required: true },

    email       : String,
    ...
})
```

I want `activity.begin_date , registration.id , registration.email` in the same query. How can I do? I've found some solutions on the internet, but still don't know whether using populate or aggregation `$lookup` (this one seems new).

Here's how I tried, but not working at all.

```
models.Registration.aggregate([

        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "Activity",
                localField: "activity_id",
                foreignField: "activity_id",
                as: "activity_docs"
            }
        },
        {"$unwind" : "activity_docs"},

    ], function( err , result ){
        if(result){
            fullDoc = result;
        }else{
            next( err );
        }
    })
```

Comment: what is issue you are getting.? can you also add sample data. and  result data. by looking at your code I could find any issue. the  $lookup should work

Comment: The compiler just past these code and I got "$lookup is not defined"

Comment: I was such an idiot... $lookup requires MongoDB 3.2. Mine is 2.6

Comment: you can answer your own question and accept it. for future, viewers.

Answer (score 2):

activity_id should be `ObjectId` data type. [ObjectId documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

If you want to use `pupoluate`, you must to use  `ref` to the other schema.
[Population documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
var activitySchema = new Schema({

    begin_date : String,
    ...
})
var Activity= mongoose.model('Activity', activitySchema );


var registrationSchema = new Schema({

    activity_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'Activity', required: true}, 
    email       : String,
    ...
})



  var Registration = mongoose.model('Registration', registrationSchema);
```

So the query such as :

```
var query = Registration.find({_id: 'registration_id parameter'});
query.select('_id activity_id email');
query.populate('activity_id','_id begin_date');
query.exec(function(error,result){
   if(error){
        /// handle error
   }else{
       // handle result
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you mean  I have to change my activity_id(value) to ObjectId("xxxxxxx")? Cuz I'm told that the activty_id is ruled. I can't change its value

Comment: What do you mean about rule? Mongo auto provide primary key ( _id ) for you !. So you don't need define ``activity_id`` for activity collection.